# Running a project's Setup, created in VS 2012 on other PC's

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012

i developed a project in visual studio 12 using C# and sql server 2012, i exported my project and a setup file was created. how can  that setup  run on any other computer? I mean that what are requirements for a PC to be able to run my setup On it. Specifically related to databases as my project is dependent on database retrivals (Insert,Delete,Modify).
Thanks.

Comment: What is your *specific* problem?

Answer (score 0):

in any computer that have a near configuration to yours or better !
 if it's a small programme it can work in any computer running under windows xp or any other newest version (it can cause design problems ""at least with Xp"" -_- )

and for database the computer where u'll install this programme must have sql ! if it doesn't u need to add sql express to your setup ! or work with Access or similar .. !

i hope this was helpfull ^^